# Div background replicate body

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve what is displayed in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siroQ.jpg

The body will have the big colored background and the little circle must be transparent and have the same background position as the body. Even if the circle is inside another div with another background. The background doesn't have to be transparent, but should look like.

Dunno even if this is possible at all.
My solution so far is for the circle to use the same background and reposition the background with minus values depending of the circle div position in the parent. All worked fine if the body bg would be simple set, but I need the body background-size: cover;

The HTML:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.d1 {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.d2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: -500px -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">Some info in the circle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add code that you have tried

Comment: Create a Fiddle demo helps us to understand more.

Comment: I've been trying to come at this from a different angle, but unfortunately I've run out of time. The idea was not to set any background image on the smaller circles, but instead to remove the border from the larger circles and then use pseudo elements on the smaller circles to create arcs and position them accordingly to replicate the border of the larger circle. Apologies for not being able to provide any code but, hopefully, this comment might set you on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this. Just set the background of the body and the background image of each circle.

```css
body {
background: url(http://maryschuler.com/wp-content/gallery/april08/univexpansion.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
margin: 12.5%;
}
.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
border: solid 2px #fff;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 100%;
height: 0;
position: relative;
}
.circle .region {
border-radius: 50%;
border: solid 2px #fff;
width: 25%;
padding-top: 25%;
height: 0;
background: url(http://maryschuler.com/wp-content/gallery/april08/univexpansion.jpg) no-repeat center top;
background-size:  100vw;
position: absolute;
clip-path: rect(10px, 20px, 30px, 40px);
}
.circle .north {
top: -12.5%; 
left: 50%;
margin-left: -12.5%;
}
.circle .east {
top: 50%;
right: -12.5%;
margin-top: -12.5%;
background-position: right center;
}
.circle .south {
bottom: -12.5%; 
left: 50%;
margin-left: -12.5%;
background-position: center bottom;
}
.circle .west {
top: 50%;
left: -12.5%;
margin-top: -12.5%;
background-position: left center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    
    <div class="region north"></div>
    <div class="region east"></div>
    <div class="region south"></div>
    <div class="region west"></div>       
    
</div>
```

Although this is a rather crude method, you could investigate clip-path as a way of clipping a shape.

For more information on clip-path see this excellent article on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/).

Comment: This is cool. But I need the background to be the image. Not a color.

Comment: I don't have the graphic you used. You can change the colour to a background in your actual example.

Comment: Yes, I can change and works ok. But doesnt work ok if I set background-size: cover;

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc I see what you mean. I have adjusted my example to use the same background in each region which gives a good approximation. However, its by no means perfect so I would suggest you investigate the clip-path property and see if that could work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use transparent background?

```
.d2 {
  background: transparent;
}
```

You can just as well leave it out – as `transparent` is the default value for `background`.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris said, but just repeat a class and use ID's and background-color: transparent!

[**JSFiddle - DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/xtxmwr0v/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);
    margin: 12.5%;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    width: 25%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    height: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
}
#big {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#north {
    top: -12.5%; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
}
#east {
    top: 50%; right: -12.5%;
    margin-top: -12.5%;
}
#south {
    bottom: -12.5%; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
}
#west {
    top: 50%; left: -12.5%;
    margin-top: -12.5%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle" id="big">        
    <div class="circle" id="north"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="east"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="south"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="west"></div>               
</div>
```

EDIT:
I see the problem of using transparent background now. Trying to solve it.

Comment: Yes. That's my issue also. Don't know if can be fixed from css. I'm thinking to add another element, positioned relative and have top, left with minus values depending on the position of circle elemenet. Than calculate the size to match body size.

Comment: I think there is no way of accomplishing a good end result with a gradient on the background using CSS.

The solution would be using .PNG images or making an animation inside a Canvas element. 

Maybe someone comes up with a better solution! D=